# Error en view edit en laravel 5.8

Tags: laravel

Estoy obteniendo el siguiente error y no se que ocurre

> Undefined variable: categorias (View:
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\PracticaLaravel\resources\views\empleados\partials\edit-fields.blade.php)
>   (View:
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\PracticaLaravel\resources\views\empleados\partials\edit-fields.blade.php)

Quiero traerme datos de la tabla "categorías" a mi tabla empleados para modificarla, cambiarle la categoría a mi empleado, en la vista de registrar un nuevo empleado, lo registra y me trae los datos de mi otra vista "categorías", o sea, las otras categorías ya registradas, para crear un empleado con su categoría, pero al momento de editar el empleado, ejemplo, cambiar la categoría, no me deja, me sale el error arriba señalado.

Esta es mi función `edit` y `update` de mi controlador de empleados

```
public function edit($id_empleado)
    {
        $empleado1=Empleados::find($id_empleado); 

        return view('empleados.edit',['empleadoActualizar'=>$empleado1]);
    }

    /**
     * Update the specified resource in storage.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @param  \App\Empleados  $empleados
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function update(Request $request, $id_empleado)
    {

        $empleado = Empleados::find($id_empleado);
        $empleado->nombres=$request->nombres;
        $empleado->apellidos=$request->apellidos;
        $empleado->nacionalidad=$request->nacionalidad;
        $empleado->cedula=$request->cedula;
        $empleado->email=$request->email;
        $empleado->cel=$request->cel;
        $empleado->local=$request->local;
        $empleado->direccion=$request->direccion;
        $empleado->id_usuario=1;


        $empleado->save();

        return redirect()->to('/empleados');

    }
```

Esto es en la vista, donde quiero que me traiga los datos de categoría para cambiarlos por cualquiera de las otras categorías ya registradas.

```
<div class="row">

        <section class="col-lg-12 connectedSortable">
          <div class="row">
            <div class="col col-md 12">
                Actualizar Empleado </div>
          </div>
 <form action="../update/{{  $empleadoActualizar->id}}" method="POST">
        @method('PUT')
        @csrf


                @include('empleados.partials.edit-fields')
</form>
```

el `empleados.partials.edit-fields` tiene todos los datos de los campos que se registraran pero el error lo da es en el de categorías, que es este

```
<div class="col col-md-2">
        <label>Categoria</label>
    </div>
    <div class="col col-md-10">
        <select  name="id_categoria" id="id_categoria"  title="Seleccione una categoria" class="form-control">
            @foreach ($categorias as $key)
            <option value="{{ $key->id }}">{{ $key->categoria }}</option>
        @endforeach
    </select>
    </div>
```

Cambien incluyo los datos del modelo de "empleados"

```
class Empleados extends Model
{
    protected $table='empleados';

    protected $fillable=['nombres','apellidos','nacionalidad','cedula','email','cel','local','direccion','id_usuario','id_categoria'];

    public function usuario()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\User','id_usuario');
    }

    public function categorias()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Categorias','id_categoria');
    }
}
```

Creo que con eso bastaría, aunque tengo bastante entendido que el error esta en el controlador en la función y en la forma del `field` de categorías en la vista.

Comment: Te hace falta la consulta que obtiene a las categorías o al menos yo no la veo

Comment: Igual puedes construirla, algo como `$categorias = Categoria::all();`  e iterar la colección con un `foreach` en la vista, lo que no me queda claro es: ¿sólo vas a iterar los datos de las categorías o vas a consultar algún dato relacionado con las mismas?

Comment: Me paso algo similar, no sera que tienes otro nombre fuera del estandar en tu FK de la relacion?
`public function categorias()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Categorias','id_categoria','nombre de foreign key');
    }`